# Mockito.mock is not overriding the value of a called class in method

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I have the following two classes

```
public class ClassA {
    private String v1;

    public String getV1() {
        return v1;
    }

    public void setV1(String v1) {
        this.v1 = v1;
    }

}


public class ClassB {
    public String op1(String val) {
        ClassA ca = new ClassA();
        ca.setV1(val);
        return "Hello->" + ca.getV1();
    }

}
```

Here is my testing code

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class ClassBTest {
    @Test
    public void testOp1() {

        ClassA classA= Mockito.mock(ClassA.class);
        when(classA.getV1()).thenReturn("TTT");
        ClassB classB = new ClassB();
        String out = classB.op1("dd");
        System.out.println(out);
        assertTrue(out.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello->TTT"));
    }
}
```

I am not sure why the test is failing, the method `classB.op1("dd");` is returning `Hello->dd` as if the mock is not being used, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing ClassB

```
public class ClassB {
    private ClassA ca;
    public String op1(ClassA caa) {
        this. ca = caa;
        ca.setV1("val");
        return "Hello->" + ca.getV1();
    }

}
```

and then for the test code

```
 @Test
    public void testOp1() {

        ClassA classA= Mockito.mock(ClassA.class);
        when(classA.getV1()).thenReturn("TTT");
        ClassB classB = new ClassB();
        String out = classB.op1(classA);
        System.out.println(out);
        assertTrue(out.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello->TTT"));
    }
```